# SpringWebFlux Error with @EnableWebFlux annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I'm using spring boot 2.1.1 version and use `@EnableWebFlux` but I got some errors.

Errors are

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application
```

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Why are you manually enabling web flux? If that is on your class path Spring Boot will automatically enable it. The same applies to the web mvc part. Looks like you have both the `spring-webmvc` as well as the `spring-webflux` jars on your classpath trigger both to be configured.

Comment: Ok. But If I want to configure WebFlux , how can I do it. Via enabling @EnableWebFlux and exends from WebFluxConfigurer.class ?

Comment: You don't need `@EnableWebFlux` as Spring Boot automatically does that for you. If you want to customize the configuration just create an `WebFluxConfigurer` in your project and add an `@Configuration` annotation to it.

Comment: Aha understood thanks a lot

Comment: And also make sure you don't have both the web and WebFlux jars on your classpath else Spring Boot will attempt to configure both. Which as you already noticed, isn't allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux enabled in [Spring SPR-16609](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16609)

> enabling MVC and WebFlux in the same application context which triggers a conflict
>
> you can't have them in the same process currently.

It offers a workaround to use  use reactive repositories:

> However, you can use reactive repositories from your existing Spring MVC application, and return the reactive types (Flux or Mono), from Spring MVC controller methods.

Comment: I did not use SpringMvc .

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev so remove `@EnableWebFlux` from your code

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev If an answer helped you can accept it by click on **V** sign to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-web-environment) and SpringFramework Collaborator [Juergen Hoeller](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21150#issuecomment-453469100), you can have both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux present in the same app. In this way, you are using Spring MVC by default, while you can have reactively enabled endpoints at the same time. Keep in mind, it is essentially a servlet-based MVC app you are using.

If you also have `@EnableWebFlux` on top of that, you mean that you wish to strictly turn this into a reactive web application.

My suggestion is to turn off `@EnableWebFlux` and keep your application straightly MVC-based. You can still use some of the reactive features such as `Mono<>` and `Flux<>` by importing Webflux dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue as using io.springfox with Spring-WebFlux.
I changed to use springdoc and solved the issue: https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

For sample detail you can check in this: https://github.com/mnguyencntt/springboot-webflux-swagger